# $.get from Jquery returns empty req.body when requesting from NodeJS server on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have set up a small nodeJS script which should act as a server. The idea is that I want to send a request from my HTML page using a text input and then get some data back from the nodeJS server based on this.

Below is my HTML script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h1> Welcome to my Website </h1>
        
        <!-- insert input box here -->
        <input type='text' value="cat" id='input' name='input'/>
        <input type='button' value='Search hashtag' id='search' onclick="getData();"/>

        <script>
            var getData = function(){
                // get new data based on input
                var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
                $.get('http://localhost:8080/', 
                    {mess: 'Hello'}, 
                    data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                )
            }
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would like to send the value of the `document.getElementById("input").value` to the server, but to keep it simple for now I decided just to hard code something in.

So the JSON of `{mess: 'Hello'}` should be sent to the following nodeJS server I have running:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// server
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.send(req.body);
    //res.json(req.body); also didn't work
  });
  
const port = 8080;
  
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

However, when I then open my HTML webpage (which is running on `http://localhost/tweets/main.html`) and push the button which triggers the $.get, I check the console and an empty `{}` is returned, whereas I would have expected something like my request input to have shown up `{mess: 'Hello'}`. I have also tried to just return the `req` object rather than the `req.body`, but in this case I get an error of `GET http://localhost:8080/?mess=Hello 500 (Internal Server Error)` (not sure if this additional information helps at all).

Most of the answers online have solved this problem by toggling the

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));     
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

settings, but I have tried different combinations of these and it hasn't helped.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using an unsupported version of jQuery with [known vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/version_id-286388/year-2018/Jquery-Jquery-2.1.3.html). Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: If you are going to claim you are sending JSON back to the browser then you should actually send that instead of implicitly calling `.toString()` on whatever is passed into `res.send`. Use [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer.

For client side use this:

```js
$.get('http://localhost:8080/?' + $.param({mess: 'Hello'}), data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Instead of this:

```js
$.get('http://localhost:8080/', {mess: 'Hello'}, data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Thats because `GET` requests can't send data to the server. By doing `$.param(data)` and including it to the url as a search query it can be sent to the server.

Changes for server side:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Content-type', 'application/json');
  res.send(req.query); // Use req.query as it parses the url stringified by $.param(data)
  // res.json(req.query); this can now work
});
```

Comment: The first half of your answer is a complete red herring. a jQuery.get  does support the passing of an object to be parametrised into the query string. You can see it working in the URL in the error message quoted in the question!

Answer (score 2):

GET requests do not have bodies at all. Data for a GET request is encoded in the URL.

You can see that in your error:

> ```
> http://localhost:8080/?mess=Hello
> ```

With express you can read that with [`query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), not `body`.